# Create two debian packages with intersecting files

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm trying to create two binary debian packages with `dpkg-deb` utility. The feature is that part of the files has the same name and path. So when I install one package after another I get error:
file of package A conflicts with file in package B.

Can you advice solution for this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. You can't have two packages installing the same file, true, but you need to tell us why you want that in the first place so that we can give you an alternative.

Comment: @Andreas Bombe I want the second package to save functionality after I delete the first. So shared file must exist until I remain both packages.

Answer (score 3):

Going by your comment, both packages need the same files for themselves (as opposed to providing variants of the same file, for example).

The solution for that is to simply split out the common files into a third package and have the other two packages both depend on it. This is a pretty common case in Debian, most packages with a name ending in "-common" contain files shared by a family of packages.

Answer (score 1):

When two packages both want to provide the same file, they both need to use `update-alternatives` -- effectively, they will provide different files, plus a facility for the system administrator to have the "contested" file be a symlink to one or the other.

Comment: For the record, I upvoted the other answer, too; probably go there first.